# Netlogo - how to count turtles number around a specific turtle

Tags: netlogo

I need to "do-something-special" if around yellow turtle there is at least 3 blue turtles . Is the code bellow correct?
I tried

```
ask turtles with [color = yellow]
  [
  if count turtles in-radius 1 with [color = blue] >= 3
  [do-something-special]
]
```

`do-something-special` should remove (disappear) 3 of blue turtles and current yellow one

Did I do the location of relevant turtles correctly and how do I kill them after I find them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hannah's answer is good but the linked example won't fully fix your problem. Since you will be using the set of close agents twice (once to count and once to potentially remove some), you should also create an agentset for efficiency reasons (you don't want to create it twice). Here is a full solution.

```
ask turtles with [color = yellow]
[ let near-blue turtles in-radius 1 with [color = blue]
  if count near-blue >= 3
  [ ask n-of 3 near-blue [die]
    die
  ]
]
```

Also, if you don't care about the exactness of the radius, an alternative to `turtles in-radius 1` would be `turtles-on (patch-set neighbors patch-here)`, which is all the turtles on the neighbouring and same patches to wherever your asker turtle is sitting.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment your code counts the amount of turtles that are blue in the radius of one patch around the yellow turtle. If the amount of blue turtles is bigger/equal 3 the yellow turtles die if you use the "die" command instead of "do-something-special". So it looks as follows.

```
 ask turtles with [color = yellow]
 [
 if count turtles in-radius 1 with [color = blue] >= 3
   [die]
 ]
```

Maybe you can merge the code with the following [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29896493/define-neighbor-turtles-using-in-radius-or-distance) and then kill the neighbors.

Comment: Thanks,But I also need to kill 3 blue turtles